# How to convert a python project (pycharm) into exe file

Tags: python, exe, converters

I've made a game Alien_Invasion using PyCharm IDE and pygame, and I want to convert all the project into an .exe file to be able to run the game on machines which doesn't have python or pygame.
I've tried pyinstaller but when it converts the main python file and I run it and it doesn't work.
Here is the link for my project:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-1gv4zRb-ZTK8NXEKPu7GSYxsownvJ-A?usp=sharing

Comment: "doesn't work" is not helpful, not at all.

Comment: when I go to dist and run the created exe file it opens the game window, nothing happens and suddenly it closes the window and finishing the program